# MySQL: Getting columns by Value priorities

Tags: mysql

I am working on a mySQL issue. I want to setup a translation system, where keys (placeholders) are saved in the tblkeys and the translations are stored in tbltranslations.

Every user in the system has a language setting and I want the system to use English, when the translation in the user's language is not available.

```
SELECT * FROM tblkeys, tbltranslations 
WHERE
tblkeys.fiproject = 1
AND tbltranslations.fiproject = tblkeys.fiproject
AND tbltranslations.fikey = tblkeys.idkey
AND (tbltranslations.dtlanguage = 'de' OR tbltranslations.dtlanguage = 'en')
GROUP BY tblkeys.idkey
```

Here I used a simply OR for demonstrating what I mean. The problem, I want the system to prefer **de**, but if not available use **en** as dtlanguage.

How could I manage that?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two left joins. One joining all DE strings, one for joining all EN strings and then add an IFNULL(de.text, en.text) in your select

```
selectr tblkeys.idkey, ifnull(de.translation, en.translation)
from tblkeys
left join 
(select idkey, translation from tbltranslations where tbltranslations.dtlanguage = 'de') de 
on de.idkey = tblkeys.idkey
left join
(select idkey, translation from tbltranslations where tbltranslations.dtlanguage = 'en') en
on en.idkey = tblkeys.idkey
```

Comment: +1, very clever. You have a typo, the second sub-query's alias should be `en`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,
   IF( @key = tblkeys.idkey, @row := @row + 1, @row := 0 ),
   @key := tblkeys.idkey
   FROM tblkeys, tbltranslations
   JOIN ( SELECT @row := 0, @key := 0 ) AS initialize
   WHERE tblkeys.fiproject = 1 AND
         tbltranslations.fiproject = tblkeys.fiproject AND
         tbltranslations.fikey = tblkeys.idkey AND
         tbltranslations.dtlanguage IN( 'de', 'en' ) AND
         @row = 0
   ORDER BY FIELD( tbltranslations.dtlanguage, 'de', 'en' )
```