# Translation query

Tags: mysql, internationalization

I have a MySQL table with translations. Now I am searching for a query that returns me the first translation matching a given list of languages:

Lets say there are 4 translations of a string available:

```
id          lang     translation
--------------------------------
greeting    en       hey!
greeting    de       Hallo.
greeting    de_at    Servus!
greeting    de_ch    Grüezi
```

Desired result of the query depending on a given language list:

```
language list    result
-----------------------
de,en            Hallo.
en,de            hey!
de_at,de,en      Servus!
```

Is this possible in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE( de_at.translation, de.translation, en.translation )
  FROM (SELECT 'greeting' AS id) AS id
  LEFT JOIN translations AS de_at ON( de_at.lang = 'de_at' AND id.id = de_at.id )
  LEFT JOIN translations AS de ON( de.lang = 'de' AND id.id = de.id )
  LEFT JOIN translations AS en ON( en.lang = 'en' AND id.id = en.id )
```

I should credit [Eddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050026/mysql-getting-columns-by-value-priorities/7050133#7050133) for this technique.

Comment: Has this solution any advantages over pulsars solution?

Comment: pulsar's query will not be able to use indexes because it is using `IN()` in WHERE clause, so for each phrase translation it has to do a full table scan, considering that most probably you will be doing lots of such translations in your application that would be a huge overhead.

Comment: Also with little modification you will be able to fetch multiple translations from the db with a single query which will further speed things up, that wouldn't be possible with pulsar's solution.

Comment: @stofl I changed the nested `IFNULL()`s to `COALESCE()` which is more readable, I also added `de_at.lang =`, etc... to the `ON()` clauses which I forgot. [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns the first non-NULL value in the list. Do you know how [sub-queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) work? What about [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)? and LEFT JOIN in particular? read about those, if you still have questions let me know.

Comment: I don't understand why you use this subquery. Why not:  `SELECT COALESCE( de_at.translation, de.translation, en.translation )
  FROM translations AS de_at ON( de_at.lang = 'de_at' AND de_at.id = 'greeting')
  LEFT JOIN translations AS de ON( de.lang = 'de' AND de_at.id = 'greeting')
  LEFT JOIN translations AS en ON( en.lang = 'en' AND de_at.id = 'greeting')
`

Comment: @stofl That subquery will let you fetch multiple translations at once in future while still using the index, it becomes something like this: `( (SELECT 'greeting' AS id) UNION (SELECT 'goodbye') UNION (SELECT 'someotherid') ) AS id`. If you want to get only one translation at a time the query you mentioned above will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM translations t WHERE id = 'greeting' AND lang IN ('de_at', 'de', 'en') ORDER BY FIELD(lang, 'de_at', 'de', 'en') LIMIT 1
```